# JAX-RS: Server-side user interface

Tags: java, user-interface, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, server-side

I have a JAX-RS REST service which needs to provide some visual server side output when a REST endpoint is invoked. Later on, I might also want to provide a user interface which an administrator will use for interacting with the web service. I could obviously build REST endpoints for this interaction, and have the administrator invoke these (from a different machine or the same machine) using a provided client application with a UI, but I would like to avoid exposing this functionality to the network. In order to make deployment easy, I would also like everything (i.e. the web service and its administrator UI) to be part of the same application.

I have found that my JAX-RS application will throw a `HeadlessException` if I try to construct a `JFrame` or any other top level UI element as described [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html). I have also found that I can avoid this by setting the system property `-Djava.awt.headless=false`.

I think I may be able to achieve what I need by setting the headless system property as above and defining a singleton startup EJB that will handle all server side UI tasks:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class UiBean {

    private JFrame frame;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            frame = new JFrame();
            // ...setup UI...
        });        
    }

    // JAX-RS resources will inject the UiBean and invoke methods as this one when UI updates are needed.
    public void updateSomeUiComponent() {
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> { ... });
    }

}
```

I realise that this design is not ideal. Are there other ways of achieving my requirements? The software being built is a prototype and time is of the essence, so I would like to avoid having to learn complete new technologies (already invested a lot in learning JAX-RS and JPA). Quick-and-dirty is ok, I guess I'm just looking for the least dirty solution ;).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't Swagger (http://swagger.io/) suit your needs? It can build interactive HTML web application - documentation according to your endpoints where you can execute them.

Comment: I don't know Swagger, but from what I can understand it is not really a tool for building a local component on the server but rather a documentation tool: "With a Swagger-enabled API, you get interactive documentation, client SDK generation and discoverability."